# Why do we need to strong name and mark webpart as safe?

Tags: web-part, best-practices

We are using SP2013 and developing webparts for clients to be used in the intranet portal.

We create the webpart, implement the logic and publish the wsp and install it on clients server.

I want to know if this is not the best practice because I have read about strong nameing and marking webpart as safe, etc. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

**Strong Names**

> Strong naming uses a private key to digitally sign an assembly. Strong
>   naming also stamps the assembly with a public key to validate the
>   signature. This technique guards against unauthorized versions of a
>   Web Part. If the public key fails to validate the digital signature,
>   SharePoint Foundation refuses to run the module. When you deploy a Web
>   Part to the bin, the recommend practice is to strong name the
>   assembly. When deploying a Web Part to the global assembly cache, the
>   assembly must have a strong name. An assembly without a strong name is
>   not recommended in SharePoint Foundation.

**Adding Safe Controls:**

> A fundamental assumption of the SharePoint Foundation technology is
>   that untrusted users can upload and create ASPX pages within the
>   system that is running SharePoint Foundation. To prevent untrusted
>   users from arbitrarily adding server-side code within ASPX pages,
>   SharePoint Foundation provides a SafeControls list. The SafeControls
>   list is a list of approved controls and Web Parts specific to your
>   SharePoint site that you have designated as safe for invocation on any
>   ASPX page within your site. This list is contained in the web.config
>   file in your web application root.

You can find these details in this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc768621%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
Also see this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8874/Strong-Names-Explained) for more details about Strong Names